# How to get Datewithtime (am/pm) difference between 2 dates in iphone sdk 4.0 and later

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to get time difference between 2 dates with date and time  in iPhone SDk .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this **Updated**

```
            NSString *strDatehere = @"22/11/2012 11:12:00 PM";
            NSDateFormatter *heredateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [heredateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"]; // set date formate with your dates

            NSDate *datehere = [heredateFormatter dateFromString: strDatehere];

            NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:datehere];

            double minutes = timeDifference / 60;

            double hours = minutes / 60;

            double seconds = timeDifference;

            double days = minutes / 1440;


            NSLog(@"%.0f, %.0f, %.0f, %.0f", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Comment: thanks paras joshi for help , but please suggest me how to  identify AM/PM of both date when both the date are same.

Comment: @jaydevsingh mate just set your start and end date in calender and try with code mate see Updated answer mate.. :) i hope this help you..

Comment: @jaydevsingh see this answer with example with entering date ..

Comment: @jaydevsingh if any problem then tell me otherwise just inform that its working .. :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually find out difference in seconds and calculate ceil(diffInSeconds/86400).

Also Following Works

```
NSDate *endDate=[dateFormat dateFromString:now];
NSTimeInterval interval = [YourDate timeIntervalSinceDate:endDate];
int diff=interval/86400;//for converting seconds into days.
```